# TypeScript/Express: Method still not being exported

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have one method in my `authentication-service.ts` file that is not successfully exporting for some reason. This is what the method looks like:

```
interface AuthResult {
  httpCode: number;
  message: string;
}

function verifyAuth(req: Request): Promise<AuthResult> {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let verifyResult: AuthResult = {
      httpCode: 200,
      message: 'OK'
  };

const authHeader: string | undefined = req.headers["authorization"];

if (!authHeader) {
  verifyResult.httpCode = 400;
  verifyResult.message = 'missing Authorization in headers';
  reject(verifyResult);
}

let service: string | undefined = undefined;
if (Object.keys(req.headers).includes("looney-service") && !Array.isArray(req.headers["looney-service"])) {
  service = req.headers["looney-service"];
}

if (!service) {
  verifyResult.httpCode = 400;
  verifyResult.message = 'missing Looney-Service in headers';
  reject(verifyResult);
}

if (authHeader && service) {
  const token: string | null = getTokenFromAuth(authHeader);
  if (token) {
    const result: string = await verifyService(service, token).catch(err => {
      console.log('verifyAuth caught error!', err);
      return err;
    });
    if (result == 'OK') {
      verifyResult.httpCode = 200;
      verifyResult.message = result;
      resolve(verifyResult);
    } else {
      verifyResult.httpCode = 403;
      verifyResult.message = result;
      reject(verifyResult);
    }
  } else {
    verifyResult.httpCode = 403;
    verifyResult.message = 'missing token';
    reject(verifyResult);
  }
}
  });
}

export { getServiceConfig, getServicePublicKey, verifyService, genJwt, getTokenFromAuth, AuthResult, verifyAuth }
```

I am importing the file that this method sits in like so:

`import * as auth from './services/authentication-service'`

However, when I console log `auth`, the object does not contain the `verifyAuth` method:

```
{
  getServiceConfig: [Function: getServiceConfig]
  getServicePublicKey: [Function: getServicePublicKey]
  verifyService: [Function: verifyService]
  genJwt: [Function: genJwt]
  getTokenFromAuth: [Function: getTokenFromAuth]
}
```

Why is that? TypeScript is not complaining about any type reference, all that has seemingly been corrected.

If I try to write it as a class of `export class Auth {}` and just drop all those methods in there, of course remove the `function` keyword and add the reference to `this`. I still get an issue with `verifyAuth()` method, in that case it would say `Property 'verifyAuth' does not exist on type` typeof Auth'`, what is the deal with this` verifyAuth` method?

Comment: Do you have other exports in that file? This looks like a default-export; I'm not sure. Try `import auth from ...`

Comment: This looks about right. Maybe your IDE is caching the file?

Comment: @Thomas, so if you look towards the bottom we are exporting all the methods like so: `export { getServiceConfig, getServicePublicKey, verifyService, genJwt, getTokenFromAuth, AuthResult, verifyAuth }` including one interface. So if I do `export default auth` there is no `auth` in that file.

Comment: @OFRBG, the error is not in compiling, I get the error when I try to hit an endpoint on the API. It compiles fine, when I try to hit an endpoint is when it tells me that `auth.verifyAuth()` is not a function.

Comment: No, I wrote that you should try to change your import to `import auth from ...` not your export. and about VS code: `Ctrl+Shift+P` and `TypeScript: Restart TS server` often helps when TS is lagging behind and doesn't keep up with your changes.

Comment: @Thomas, yes but to change the import to `import auth from...` it would mean I need an `default export` and thats the error it will generate. I cleaned the cache on my VS Code, the problem is still there. I get the error when I try to hit an endpoint.

Comment: @Thomas, I tried dropping those methods in a class type of file and just do `export class Auth`, but it still complains about that `verifyAuth`. I added what I did in the OP.

Comment: That's beyond my ability to remote debug this. I don't use that syntax. Usually I export each function/const/type seperately `export function foo(){...}` and/or use a `export default something`. I don't know what `export { ... }` constructs and what the pitfalls are, that's why my first assumption was that it might generate a default export. Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @Thomas, I just exported the function using the syntax you use, `export function foo() {}` and I still do not see `verifyAuth` as a function inside the `auth` object. By the way I do not write JavaScript in that manner, this is not my code, this is someone who got stuck in CommonJS way and never learned TypeScript and now I am supposed to add to this work, but something is amiss with that `verifyAuth` method in particular.

Comment: Is `AuthResult` a type defined in this module? Or is it just a type declaration (with no concrete implementation)? Perhaps that's causing issue that TS is not reporting?

Comment: @JeffMercado, `AuthResult` is an interface. I added it in the OP.

Comment: @JeffMercado, that solved it. Instead of exporting the interface like so: `export {}` I just added the `export` keyword to the interface.